# Is the openfloor plan without a private desk common?

Tags: software-industry, work-environment, company-culture, office-layout

If this has been asked elsewhere, sorry. I looked and could not find anything likely.

I am a software engineer for a good size technology company and we have been informed we are moving to an open floor plan model.  That part, I have seen over and over but what I have not seen is, I won't have a private desk.  Everyday, I will come in to the office, fetch my personal effects out of a locker and go in search of a place to work.  At the end of the day, I will have to pack up everything before going home since there is a very good chance I won't have the same seat tomorrow.  I have heard rumors from another office that has already made the conversion that people commonly mill around for 15 minutes looking for an open place to sit.

I can deal with keeping my desk clean (something I don't do now) but not being able to leave my coffee cup and pencil out overnight seems excessively petty.  How about my wall calendar and the picture of my kids? Sorry. They have to be packed up as well. Notes? Manuals? Reference books? Sorry, "This is the way of the future," I have been told.

While I don't think much of the open floor plan, I have dealt with worse but I have have had a fixed place to park myself since I started working professionally.

Is this really the way of the future? Open floor plan supporters always wave their hands and say "This is what Google and Apple are doing." I don't doubt they have open areas but does anybody know if they have non-fixed seating?

I think upper management has decided this is the way they want to go, "damn the torpedoes" but I am still hoping against hope that they will listen to reasonable arguments that perhaps this is ill advised.

Does anybody have any good suggestions on what to present to management?  Somebody had the very good suggestion (before this edit) of keeping track of time spent setting up every morning and packing up every evening.  I have also seen postings of loss of productivity and disgruntled workers but most are anecdotal at best. Does hard evidence exist?  Can hard evidence exist?

Another question is how to present this to management?  We have town hall meetings with "our" vice president from time to time. I asked if this was our direction ("yes") and if there would be an allowance for the loss of productivity.  To this question, I was told that it increases productivity and this is what Millennials expect (I am a Boomer) and, these are his exact words, "...get with the program."  Most people I talk to hate the idea of the open office--much less non-assigned seating--but I seem to be the only one that is willing to make waves.

Thank you for any input.

Comment: I'm hearing about this happening in a few places from time to time - there's questions here about it. I'm not sure I've heard all the reasons people are trying it - trying to promote more communication? I think it's a bad idea, personally. But - rather than the posting a  wall of rant, would you like to ask a question that will help you and other people facing this situation?

Comment: The open desks on the floor is more common.  Not having a stationary reliable desk seems counter productive.  I wouldn't think many places would do this without seeing a negative impact on performance, but to each their own I guess.  If you want to fight it, document something objective like a signed petition on employee morale or the amount of time you waste trying to find a place and unpack all your stuff (get an average and multiply for all the people doing it, etc...)

Comment: I used to work in an office like this. A lot of people in my office had angst about it before transitioning to it, and then fell right into it. It really isn't that bad. (in practice, despite having no assigned seats, most people sit in the same place everyday anyway)

Comment: What if you have a special equipment like standing desk, extra monitors, hubs and so on?

Comment: Yes, it is becoming a trend - in the UK it's called 'hotdesking'.

Comment: RE the actual question here, will you find this in your next job. This seems to be an easy thing to verify in an interview, you should be seeing the work-space and meeting the team.

Comment: There may be an exception here or there, but overall Google has fixed seating and they don't mind people having / leaving some stuff on their desks. I'm not actually aware of any software engineering companies that **don't** have fixed seating, and companies probably wouldn't mind openly discussing this during the interview process.

Comment: @fez: Special equipment?  I wish.  I sounds like I am going to lose my (very nice) 24 monitor.   

---

I have been thinking I may practice civil disobedience and lock down my computer and park a great quantity of job related, if disposable, stuff on a desk and claiming it for my own, office coordinator be damned. I am one of the few old timers that actually knows the details and history of most our software.  If I leave (or am terminated) "there will be wailing and gnashing of teeth."

Comment: We have it at our workplace (in the UK) and, to be honest, there was some resentment initially when it was implemented. We have 2 days working from home too and there aren't enough desks for the number of staff we have, so it makes sense in our case. Over time, however, we've found that most people have their fixed desks anyway and no-one really minds moving around if they have to (as the set up is identical; we work off a laptop which we plug into a docking station).

Comment: Update:  I left my job of 12 years last Friday.  I am moving to a company that respects their employees enough to pay for floor space so everybody can have a cube.  The old company needed me a lot more than I needed them and they were practically begging me to stay but moving on is something I should have done years ago.  I have always felt that there should not be any indispensable people.  Leaving is one way to shake things up.  Maybe they will recognize the value and potential for loss of the other key players.